# Long SMB session setup delay

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, samba, wireshark

I have a Windows machine connecting to an SMB share on a local Debian server. Everything works flawlessly, when it's connected, but the first connection (either after a boot / reboot, or after resuming from a long sleep) is very slow.

In the screenshot below you can see that it takes ~6.7 seconds for Windows to start setting up the session. I can live with the delay, but this also breaks file descriptors upon waking up, so if I had a media file open before suspending, I'm unable to resume playing it.

[image: Screenshot from Wireshark]

How do I fix this? Where do I look?

Comment: I got the exact same problem. Did you ever find out what was causing the delay? I asked a question at ServerFault and tried Wireshark and got the same results as you: http://serverfault.com/questions/817004/initial-delay-when-browsing-smb-share-from-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but in a Windows domain environment. In my case most of the delay was caused by a VirtualBox network interface, see: https://serverfault.com/a/817088/147178

Comment: Thanks, looks promising! I'm not using network drives anymore, so can't verify if it helps, but I do have VirtualBox installed, and the delay is too similar to be something else.